# Increase score if match string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query with a bunch of `"filter": []` 
Then a bunch of scoring functions:

`"must": [ { "function_score": { "functions": [ ... ] } } ]`

I am trying to have documents with a specific keyword to rank higher than if they dont have it.

I tried to add this into my `functions` array:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "match": {
            "[MY FIELD]": "[MY KEYWORD]"
        }
    },
    "weight": 1
}
```

But I think it is doing the opposite, it is adding a coefficient below 1 to the one which match and therefor making the document with `MY KEYWORD` to rank lower.

I tried to search for a `not` method to match for all the one without `MY KEYWORD` but I cannot find anything in the context of `functions`. I found `match_not` but it doesnt work there.

My goal is if you have 2 exact same documents, one with `MY KEYWORD` and one without, I want to one with to have a higher score.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The one solution I found is:

```
{
    "script_score" : {
        "script" : {
          "inline": "String tmp = null; for (a in doc['MY_FIELD']) {tmp = a;} return tmp == 'MY_KEYWORD' ? 1.0 : DECAY_VALUE",
          "lang": "painless"
        }
    },
    "weight": MY_WEIGHT
}
```

I used a decay_value of 0.7

and a weight of 0.7 too.

And MY_FIELD needs to be a `type:keyword`